# Rake assets:clobber and precompile causes git merge conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Using Rails 4.0.3.  I am going to push my application updates to Heroku.  Because I was working with assets, I wanted to clean them up and create a fresh copy, so I did a clobber and precompile.  This action alone seems to have created a git merge conflict.  Or, am I missing something?  I've resolved simple conflicts in the past, but this one is new to me.  Can you please tell me how to resolve this?

The process follows:

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git status
On branch version-1.10
nothing to commit, working directory clean

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>rake assets:clobber
I, [2015-05-08T01:01:19.335136 #2408]  INFO -- : Removed D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
rm -rf D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/tmp/cache/assets

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>rake assets:clobber RAILS_ENV=production
I, [2015-05-08T01:01:53.080552 #19172]  INFO -- : Removed D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets

rm -rf D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/tmp/cache/assets

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.624102 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/DeleteRed-72974c2d1f1b09a69eaad352188195f1.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.631107 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/Icons-mini-arrow_down-de80f42604ea54e80253147693682b62.gif
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.637105 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/Icons-mini-arrow_up-e617865776fb86a10537559fc2754516.gif
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.685105 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/car-549da5fcc265386244e55bcc780c7b28.ico
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.710107 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/my_app_redesign_color01-cd3e7ed32fd0c6d156a8c5c9d2ff295a.jpg
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.731126 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/my_app_redesign_color02-07e39a32da11981bf742fb8202b096ac.jpg
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.782144 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/rails-388e5a3b3ae0e085310a99f179f8291e.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.796116 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/small_x1-3c5f818780cc27bfa11f1e8e6c087f8d.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.813116 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/small_x2-7fae117327e56b60d98872466ab71b3b.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.820116 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/sort_asc-c3327239e8dc0ce9b9288525c3d30d26.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.827116 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/sort_both-67d0bbd65de0d3462b31c7ee0fa29bc5.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:33.835122 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/sort_desc-5c901fc353f19d7583b77307851c654d.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:42.015594 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/application-1798a300bc1f81021835b0756391310e.js
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.105732 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/application-3aaccdca55fee944386353ada7eea718.css
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.134736 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-2858f48657aa30e02d2095342471ba00.eot
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.141736 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-648858aa889a3d23a6e3414ba8a0a02d.svg
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.149733 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-2858f48657aa30e02d2095342471ba00.ttf
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.157749 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-2858f48657aa30e02d2095342471ba00.woff
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.172739 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100-1fa83da988c496f3b6b4a3132cd4cc63.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.186741 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100-1a84f396ed6cc5bdc44ae13e12c9413b.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.203741 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400-46a7e08af592714fc92f4d87aa2fca36.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.218742 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400-5f6e0ce2d23eab39b1b83abf05f99801.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.234744 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400-76719558bfb6b9566c2b342b516d1756.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.249744 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400-cdb62f296e7f3c6b81584cc81ff76eeb.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.264746 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400-b22e32502f5f6c863f05ff9810edaa7e.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.281738 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100-1cb58b68cf84331f41762764b70fa8ef.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.324748 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240-ea6f8ed84f165dd1c63d808ec96acac9.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.348748 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240-1995ab092f581d8377229fadb3fd3e80.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.393748 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-icons_454545_256x240-ca04cac8ea32b6f64180b393767edf7a.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.409749 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-icons_888888_256x240-bfea01de5d1c764771cebbf65d29e0ae.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.425753 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/jquery-ui/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240-16a4f218fe0bc71ff70cd8ed1771d7e0.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.485757 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/back_disabled-2e043033788cbcf14ae236ba2eeadee8.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.514757 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/back_enabled-ffc4b78cfa00d243d5519e50e27b5a25.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.576761 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/back_enabled_hover-a8b3cd1ae492dfbfe5e7af736750d72f.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.610762 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/background-3830dcf30531da31ae142f6ffa6e8457.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.655766 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/button-823be07e05e95f1b91dd7eb427c5c912.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.681770 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/collection-9e2788624a471583e80fc45b1f127a37.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.713771 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/collection_hover-d07133b5bf48cff29661eb6d850a7e85.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.735762 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/copy-eb7e698ba0c415a51347efe353abe1ce.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.762781 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/copy_hover-31e4694d3ee212559ae8cb09e1413a30.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.790799 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/csv-a826cb6f02a8755a6eb9f2b8051aff78.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.817777 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/csv_hover-49279f2880fafc7a95feb0b5b9c8fc24.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.843778 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/filler-e3f09fe70da389e038490135d095fb3d.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.863779 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/insert-9b514534dc3e295db24f4eeaeb0dba6f.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.889773 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/loading-background-0c5044dfffc24a4b4d3d4c49aab3afdb.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.914796 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/pdf-e40d4977e19d068e152584c00be17f62.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.938790 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/pdf_hover-34e9686212f592f24ea473c6c2d15e3e.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:02:59.968792 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/print-5bb36a9a8dd59c287b3123635b4a5fde.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.001779 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/print_hover-e389208bc53c2bd350e88b5917bd2c5f.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.041790 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/xls-4fd2177e8c25751a1515eb24754c253f.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.065796 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/xls_hover-4acc4c8c272ec8b8aab78d368a52318b.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.097794 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/favicon-341436b780b92a3b318b49bab25a873e.ico
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.122795 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/forward_disabled-038e00252a33b149865def6eb7c070eb.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.143806 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/forward_enabled-8dfc268d3c294b7f4f278fba197191a2.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.171798 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/forward_enabled_hover-bda11f9300cc8a0c4f5241a8f0413074.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.195801 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/foundation/sort_asc-e9ea7d12b915dd5d2fc3c183c2281ff5.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.220802 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/foundation/sort_asc_disabled-9ae5f25540cc831074ef8f4d089b8fe0.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.258800 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/foundation/sort_both-3950cff0b82a0a66e490e77ebaf0b096.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.297798 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/foundation/sort_desc-3570c455229f720ad6721dd5ad40cae6.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.330803 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/foundation/sort_desc_disabled-10a749a2c2bfb14557136b4f665f80bb.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.347807 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/minus-d2ac7be6d76c50e9cb233db5597832dc.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.364808 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/plus-a6f41f2a37b65403175819cd739cdd98.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.388812 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/sort_asc-e9ea7d12b915dd5d2fc3c183c2281ff5.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.405813 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/sort_asc_disabled-0784e0dbe2aada0c1c7af14db00f0f5c.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.425813 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/sort_both-3950cff0b82a0a66e490e77ebaf0b096.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.448813 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/sort_desc-3570c455229f720ad6721dd5ad40cae6.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.473816 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/sort_desc_disabled-10a749a2c2bfb14557136b4f665f80bb.png
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.503813 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/as3/ZeroClipboard-81de8a64fbae2fa83c5512d540b48e21.as
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.521820 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf-ba907045edd5a364a919f76731ffe9f5.as
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.554817 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/as3/lib/AlivePDF-537866e1cd4473a99eba0f8a4097f19d.swc
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.587819 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls-699fcec8370ef13b4606dd9f47ba0218.swf
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.619815 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf-666e4aef3ce6c8595f6a97b4c05b619e.swf
I, [2015-05-08T01:03:00.652826 #16836]  INFO -- : Writing D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-11/projects/myapp/public/assets
/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-5840366f483f32e8e39f6d867b9dccd3.woff2

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git add --all
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/assets/application-1798a300bc1f81021835b0756391310e.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/assets/application-3aaccdca55fee944386353ada7eea718.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/assets/dataTables/extras/as3/ZeroClipboard-81de8a64fbae2fa83c5512d540b48e
21.as.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/assets/dataTables/extras/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf-ba907045edd5a364a919f76731f
fe9f5.as.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git commit -m "clobber and precompile"
[version-1.10 c1bf1bb] clobber and precompile
 5 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 569 deletions(-)
 rename public/assets/{manifest-f6ed403257c515fde435a4efeec74088.json => manifest-f45e404b1fde7bd606849e1b56691dbe.json}
 (99%)
 delete mode 100644 public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.coffee
 delete mode 100644 public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.map

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git merge version-1.10
warning: Cannot merge binary files: public/assets/application-65733beab0cc71ee0dc6ab288a7074c1.js.gz (HEAD:public/assets
/application-65733beab0cc71ee0dc6ab288a7074c1.js.gz vs. version-1.10:public/assets/application-1798a300bc1f81021835b0756
391310e.js.gz)
Removing public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.map
Removing public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.coffee
CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "public/assets/manifest-f6ed403257c515fde435a4efeec74088.json"->"public/assets/manifest
-d86323e8d0d88233e3438587840eff30.json" in branch "HEAD" rename "public/assets/manifest-f6ed403257c515fde435a4efeec74088
.json"->"public/assets/manifest-f45e404b1fde7bd606849e1b56691dbe.json" in "version-1.10"
Auto-merging public/assets/application-65733beab0cc71ee0dc6ab288a7074c1.js.gz
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/assets/application-65733beab0cc71ee0dc6ab288a7074c1.js.gz
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   public/assets/application-3aaccdca55fee944386353ada7eea718.css.gz
        deleted:    public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.coffee
        deleted:    public/assets/source_maps/bundler/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.map

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        both modified:   public/assets/application-65733beab0cc71ee0dc6ab288a7074c1.js.gz
        added by us:     public/assets/manifest-d86323e8d0d88233e3438587840eff30.json
        added by them:   public/assets/manifest-f45e404b1fde7bd606849e1b56691dbe.json
        both deleted:    public/assets/manifest-f6ed403257c515fde435a4efeec74088.json


D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\myapp>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to add precompiled assets to git at all

Comment: @FrederickCheung Aren't you then assuming that they would be precompiled where they were pushed?  Regardless, how do I solve this situation now?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled assets aren't something you would normally want to have in your git repository.  I would just add an entry for `/public/assets` to a `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your application.

Since you've already committed the compiled assets, you will want to remove them from the repo:

```
git rm --cached -r /public/assets
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean I have to precompile at the site?

Comment: Okay, just did this and Heroku executed the precompile during the push, so done.  Thanks.

Comment: That does, of course, beg the question as to why that directory is not in .gitignore by default...